# How often are heavy aircraft brake pads changed?

Tags: aircraft-maintenance, braking

How often are Boeing 747-800 and Airbus A380 aircraft brake pads changed?

Comment: A technical question: Are they actually brake _shoes_, or are they brake _pads_? The difference being shoes are used in drum brakes, while pads are used on disk brakes. I can't imagine an aircraft (especially a heavy/super) using drum brakes since disk are much more effective. (Witness all modern cars using (at least) front disk brakes (since the fronts do about 75% of the braking), and the terrifying lack of braking available in muscle cars from the '60s-'70s where 4-wheel drums were standard.)

Comment: @FreeMan pretty sure they're all disc brakes on modern airliners.

Comment: It's more like "brake plates" like clutch plates.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The 747-800 [uses carbon brakes made by the Goodrich company](http://www.boeing.com/commercial/aeromagazine/articles/qtr_03_09/article_05_1.html#fig1) and [according to this article](http://www.avm-mag.com/wheel-brake-repair-and-overhaul/),

> The entire industry is leaning towards carbon brakes, Honeywell
>   executives assert. Lufthansa Technik also sees a trend towards carbon
>   brakes, as the mean time between repairs (MTBR) for carbon brakes is
>   1,500-2,000 cycles, compared with some 1,100 cycles for steel brakes.

[Also of note, take a look at this video on the testing of the brakes](https://youtu.be/_g6UswiRCF0?t=46s).